# Can school be used without articles

Tags: articles

School always closes for holidays.

I think it should be "schools close for holidays".
Why is school used without articles here?
Thanks.

Comment: I did answer this question, but I hope some mod will move it to ELL eventually, where it belongs.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth We are in uncommon agreement. But you should supply it as an answer.

Comment: 'School' is used in various ways, some doubtless unexpected to those unfamiliar with its idiosyncrasies. _He's started going to school._ / _School's out._ / _School was over for the day._  // 'Schools close for holidays' is of course grammatical (if platitudinous); it shows the count usage ('three schools in Wigham haven't closed yet'). But 'school always closes for holidays' is a non-count usage; it refers to either the whole school educational system, or (almost as a pet, proper name) to one's own and cherished school.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, *school* can be used without any articles. The reason is that it can be used as both a count and an uncount noun; see for example the entry at the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/school?q=school_1), which clearly specifies whether a given usage is count or uncount.

In particular, that dictionary says that when *school* is used in the sense of 'a place where children go to be educated', it can be either count or uncount.

Some other examples of uncount usage, from that same dictionary, for that same sense:

> She drives the kids to **school** every morning.
>   Is Emily in/at **school** today or is she still ill?
>   What did you learn at **school** today?

Here is a sentence from a published book:

***School*** always closes for the holidays. [(source)](https://books.google.com/books?id=LP6nAwAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PT74&dq=%22School%20always%20closes%20for%22&pg=PT74#v=onepage&q=%22School%20always%20closes%20for%22&f=false)

(Which reminds me: it should be *for **the** holidays,* with the definite article in front of *holidays*.)

**Discussion**

At this point, you would no doubt like to know if there is some rule that will tell you when native speakers will use *school* as a count noun, and when as an uncount noun. Unfortunately, when it comes to the articles in general, at best there are only tendencies. Consider this example: in AmE we'd say *…once he is taken home from **the** hospital,* while in BrE we'd say *from hospital*, without the article. However, in both AmE and BrE we'd say *in the morning all the peasants went to **church***, with no article before *church*.

As far as tendencies, here is how they are usually formulated in this class of cases (from [Collins COBUILD English Guides: Articles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0003705617)):

> **6.5 Institutions in society**
>
> There are certain establishments of human society which are referred to without an article when we think of them as institutions in general rather than as specific buildings or individual places.
>
> *He was finally admitted to **hospital** with an ulcerated leg.
>
>   ...after our first victory in **court**.*
>
> Here is a list of words that can be used like this.
>
> church   court         jail         school
>   college    hospital    prison    university
>
> Normally, when you are using these words to talk about buildings they are count nouns and article usage with them is straightforward. But when you want to suggest that they are being used for their intended purpose there is no article; that is, worshipping in church, studying in school/college/university,
>   receiving medical care in hospital, being a prisoner in prison or jail, legal action in court. Often there is a different way of expressing the idea: 'She's at university' is similar to saying 'She's a student'.
>
> Here are some more examples.
>
> *...once he is taken home from **hospital**.
>
>   In the morning all the peasants went to **church**.
>
>   He left **school** at seventeen.
>
>   ...to decide whether to go to **court** or not.
>
>   His parents couldn't afford to send him to **university**.
>
>   After 11 days in **prison** they were released.*
>
> There are some differences between British and American usage here. Firstly, Americans say 'the hospital' instead of 'hospital' for institutional reference. Secondly, the word 'university' is not used in this way; the American equivalent of 'at university' is 'in college'.
>
> 'Bed' behaves in a similar way; without an article it means the place where we sleep or rest, not a particular object.
>
> *She went to **bed** and slept lightly.*

Comment: +1 but a couple of criticisms. "Which school do you attend?" is not, I feel sure, a non-count usage. You could equally have said "Which of the following three schools do you attend?". Finally, you have not included the other instance where an article can be omitted - namely where you are speaking of a specific school. e.g. "He returned to school feeling much better".

Comment: @WS2 Oops, you're right about *Which school do you attend?*; I changed that example. But can you explain why you are saying that *he returned to school feeling much better* is different from e.g. *She drives the kids to school every morning*?

Comment: You are perhaps right - my apologies. However at an individual school, they may refer to e.g something being held in "school hall", or a practice being against "school rules". There is no question as to which school is referenced as it is obvious. If you refer to @Edwin Ashworth's comment he explains further.

Answer (score 0):

"Schools always close for holidays" is a sentence about all schools.

"School always closes for holidays" is a statement about a specific (though perhaps theoretical) school. It means "My school always closes for holidays" or "One's school always closes for holidays."

"School" just works this way, where the name of the type of thing can serve as a name for the thing. Other places such as "church" and "work" can work this way, as can some relationship names like "mom" and "dad". "I need to hurry up and get to school, since Mom is already waiting for me there."

Comment: I'd say that school there is a concept, ergo, no article....

Comment: In "school is not job training; it is supposed to educate you," sure. In "I ran my fastest and managed to get to school in under 10 minutes this morning," I don't think I agree that it's being used as a concept.

Comment: School is a pain in the rear. School always closes for the holidays. School is fun, work is not. Those are not referring to school as a generic thing?